# How to persist and then retrieve external login provider's access_token

Tags: c#, angular, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using the .Net Core Angular template with individual accounts:

`dotnet new angular -au individual`

And I am adding an external Microsoft login provider thus:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddMicrosoftAccount(config => {
            config.ClientId = "***REDACTED***";
            config.ClientSecret = "***REDACTED***";
            config.SaveTokens = true;
        })
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

Then, I create a page with the `[Authorized]` attribute, and I try to retrieve the Microsoft `access_token` but it always comes up as `null`. This is how the page is built:

#### Test.cshtml

```html
@page
@model TestModel
<partial name="_LoginPartial" />
<h1>hi</h1>
<div>
    <p>Access Token</p>
    <pre>
@Model.AccessToken
</pre>
    <p>ID Token</p>
    <pre>
@Model.IdToken
</pre>
</div>
```

#### Test.cshtml.cs

```cs
[Authorize]
public class TestModel : PageModel {
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public string AccessToken;
    public string IdToken;

    public TestModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync() {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            return;
        }
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        AccessToken = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "Microsoft", "access_token");
        IdToken = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "Microsoft", "id_token");
    }
}
```

As mentioned, I only ever get `null` values for `AccessToken` and `IdToken` - what am I doing wrong?

P.S. I also tried `await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("Microsoft", "access_token")` - it also returns `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question after days of research, which culminated in me cloning the repos at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore and at https://github.com/identityserver/identityserver4 and tracking the target through the code...

The solution is to add a call to `SigninManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync` to the `Account/ExternalLogin` callback handler (method `OnGetCallbackAsync`), after verifying that the external login is successful, i.e. after the call to `_signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync` thus:

```cs
// Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(
    info.LoginProvider, 
    info.ProviderKey, 
    isPersistent: false, 
    bypassTwoFactor : true);

if (result.Succeeded) {
    await _signInManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync(info); // <-- This
    _logger.LogInformation(
        "{Name} logged in with {LoginProvider} provider.", 
        info.Principal.Identity.Name, 
        info.LoginProvider);

    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: I've been hunting for a solution to this problem for the past 4 days... And THIS is where I end up!!!